# kendoListView change event is triggered twice when selecting item

Tags: javascript, listview, select, kendo-ui, onchange

**Problem:**

When I trigger the change event by selecting the 1st element in the listview by code, the event is fired only once. 
When I trigger the change event by clicking on a listview item, the change event is triggered twice.

Any idea what could trigger this 2nd event, how to prevent it?

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="overview">
    <div id="listView"></div>
</div>

<!-- Used lib source loaded from lib server, for developers -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom libs loaded from meter, for customers/developers (very fast <0.3sec) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MeasCon/Scripts/current_values.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
/* JQuery function that is called when the DOM is done loading */
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    /* The HTML template code for the current values overview listview */
    /* .join is for multi line in javascript */
    var overview_template = [
        '<div class="overview_content" id="#:name#" >',
            '<div class="overview_content_textbox">',
                '<span class="overview_content_textbox_text">#:test#</span>',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="overview_content_led_box">',
                '<span class="led_box"><img class="led" src="/MeasCon/Content/IMAGES/#= led #.png"></span>',
            '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join("\n");

    /* the datasource for the overview listview */
    var overview_datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        transport: 
        {
            read: 
            {
                url: "../../Content/current_values_overview.json",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
    });

    /* populating the listview with the datasource as defined by the template */
    $("#listView").kendoListView(
    {
        template: kendo.template(overview_template),
        dataSource: overview_datasource,
        selectable: true,
        change: function() 
        {
            var idx = this.select().index();
            var item = this.dataSource.view()[idx];
            alert(item.name);
        },
        dataBound: function() 
        {
            //Fires when the list view has received data from the data source and it is already rendered.

            // get a reference to the list view widget
            var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");

            // selects first list view item
            listView.select(listView.element.children().first());

        }
    });

});
```

**The JSON file**

```
[
{
    "name": "Performance",
    "led": "ok_green"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the event is fired twice? Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/R6v9M/

What is `overview_content` event handler doing? What I see is that this is fired once and then `change` is fired. While if you use `trigger` the function `overview_content` is not invoked.

Comment: When loading the jsfiddle page, the change event is fired only once(this comes from the dataBound function), when clicking on the item from the listview,below the button, then the event is triggered 2 times, since I get the performance pop-up twice. for testing we can remove the overview_content since this is an empty function.

Comment: Do you mean that in my JsFiddle when you click on performance you get the alert twice? I get it only once! Which OS/Browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, in your JsFiddle example I also get the same result. I have tested this on W7 32-bit OS(using Firefox 23 and IEv8) AND on W7 64-bit OS(using Firefox 24 and IEv8)

Comment: You are right but try replacing your alert by a console.log and then it gets displayed only once (interesting!) Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/R6v9M/

Comment: I did not see any change in the new jsfiddle example? I tried adding the <div class="console"></div> and replaced the alert with kendoConsole.log(item.test); but It does not display the console box in jsfiddle?

Comment: I've never used `kendoConsole.log`, I always use native `console.log` but for your convenience check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/R6v9M/6/ (link in previous comments was wrong -was the same of the original reply-)

Comment: Ha! I did not know it was also possible, learned something new :) Yes!, it now only appears once, Thank you, I will try to implement this in my application, maybe the alert is the part that triggers the second call to the change function.. Do you think this could be possible?

Comment: Exactly, That's what I think! `alert` are pretty special in JavaScript+Browsers: it's actually the only way (afaik) to _stop_ the execution of the running `thread` other mechanism are just synchronization between running thread and tasks happening in the background as event handlers.

Comment: Man you are the best! Not only did this solve my problem, I now also am able to write console log statements to firebug debugger using console.log(), Many Thanks for your input on this topic.

Comment: Also I noticed the same problem with IE11 but not with Chrome